# Ping with explicit next-hop selection (aka Monitoring multiple default gateways)

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a linux (debian) router with *two internet connections* ***(A)*** and ***(B)***.

**(A)** is preferred, **(B)** is fallback.

I want to monitor the internet connection (and not only the availability of the gateways!) and change the default route appropriately.

1. If **(A)** is not providing internet, switch to **(B)**
2. If **(A)** is providing internet again, switch back to **(A)**.

Only problem I have is in case **(2)**. My routing table points towards a working internet so I cannot easily detect whether internet is working over link **(A)** again.

I am search for a ping or traceroute (or other diagnosis-tool) which can select the next-hop explicitly.

- `ping -r` looks promising, but can only ping a host on the lan. (It only has to write another destination address in the packet, damnit!)
- `traceroute -g gateway` looks even more promising and nearly does what I want - but sets source routing options which my next-hops deny. (Not within my administrative boundary...)

I just want a $ping, that can:

- select a source interface (and address)
- select a next-hop on that interface
- ping any arbitrary ip address

I could do evil trickery with policy-based routing but that would have production impact for all users. I would like to see a side-effect-free solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the upstream gateways on the same Ethernet segment(s) as your router? If so `nping --dest-mac …` might work. (Nping is one of the many tools that come with nmap so it may already be on your system.)

Comment: Perfect! Has a `--interface`` option which in combination with `--dest-mac` seems to be what I need! nping is contained in the debian wheezy nmap package.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/sh

IP=$1
GW=$2

route add -host $IP gw $GW
ping $IP
route del -host $IP gw $GW
```

You can also use the metric option to avoid any existing internet connection trying to use this route in the meantime.

Comment: +1 a Simple route for the external host your are testing against should be easy, so long as that external address doesn't need to be accessed for anything other then testing.  Though I do wonder why you would keep adding/removing the host route.  I am sure you could find an address for some piece of equipment at the ISP, that you would only want to every access across the link from from that ISP.

Comment: +1, like KISS solutions! But - should be a little more robust and some work on an elaborate script is acceptable. Your idea was the kind of solution I had in mind when I was talking about policy-based routing. Would have done your solution but a bit more narrow, just icmp to the mentioned host. But: want to test more than one host, something really high available. Would have to do dns-resolution and so this all is growing.

Comment: +1. I do basically the same thing w/ Cisco routers. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using iptables with the [Route Patch](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.5) to specify the gateway to use on your ICMP packets sourcing from that **(A)** interface.

Supposing your **(A)** interface is 10.0.0.1 with a default gw of 10.0.0.2

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p icmp -s 10.0.0.1 -j ROUTE --gw 10.0.0.2
```

Then `ping -I 10.0.0.1 x.x.x.x`

Comment: Yeah, think since ping-with-nexthop-selection seems from another universe I'll take this solution. Small conceptual changes here, though: assign 2 loopback IPs, explicitly use them with ping and force them via `ip rule from` to the one or other gateway.

Comment: That sounds like a great plan. Good luck!